# Create timestamp with script editor when email is sent by Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently receiving data through an RSS feed into my spreadsheet. I have a script (below) which I am hoping to run on a time trigger (every minute) to check the data and then in turn send an email out if the data meets certain criteria.

Problem: After the first email is sent out, I want to create a system to check (timestamp?) within the script if an email for that particular row of data has already been sent. Is this the best way to do this? How do I do it? Script is below.

```
function sendEmail(email_address, email_subject, email_message) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, email_subject, email_message);
}




function test_sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.setActiveCell('A2');
  var criterion_cutoff = 5;
  var i = 0;
  var addr;
  var subj;
  var msg;
  do {
    addr = cell.offset(i,0).getValue();
    subj = cell.offset(i,1).getValue();
    msg = cell.offset(i,2).getValue();
    criterion = cell.offset(i,3).getValue();

    if(criterion < criterion_cutoff) {
      sendEmail(addr,subj,msg);
      Browser.msgBox('Sending email to: ' + addr);
    }
    i++;
  } while( cell.offset(i, 0).getValue().length > 0 )

  Browser.msgBox('Done!');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want some way of marking which rows in the spreadsheet that you've already sent emails for, so that you don't send duplicates. If so, then this tutorial shows one way of doing that: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails#section2

Comment: Thanks. This helps in that I was able to successfully create an "Email_Sent" stamp but my problem is that My RSS feed moves as it is updated so that the newest input is at the top and the older information is pushed down. Since the message information and my checking criteria is generated from there for the email it also moves down. Once the information moves down, The "Email_Sent" tag is no longer beside the correct information resulting in either an email being sent twice or an email not being sent.